# How to rename group of files with increment

Tags: bash, filesystems, git-bash

How to rename group of files in directory in bash? 
For example : 
I had group of file:

```
> 0001.txt
> 0002.txt
> 0003.txt
> 0004.txt
...
```

I need that 0001.txt become 0002.txt; 0002.txt become 0003.txt and etc. 
And result should be so:

```
0002.txt
0003.txt
0004.txt
0005.txt
...
```

Comment: in that case start with the last one so that you don't overwrite some files in the process... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your filenames follow the given pattern, you can do something like this :

```
for file in `ls | egrep '^[[:digit:]]+.txt$' | sort -r`
do 
  mv $file `printf %04d $(expr ${file%.*} + 1)`.txt
done
```

**Edit**

For filenames with the prefix `tet` you can modify the script above like this :

```
for file in `ls | egrep '^tet[[:digit:]]+.txt$' | sort -r`
do 
  filename=${file%.*}
  mv $file tet`printf %04d $(expr ${filename:3} + 1)`.txt
done
```

Just for curiosity, I would appreciate if some bash experts know a way to avoid the temporary variable `filename`

Comment: but what I should to write if file will not "0001.txt", but "tet0001.txt"?

Comment: Do they all have the same prefix ?

Comment: File name start with "tet0001.txt" (like example)

Comment: Yes, it does start with `tet`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a below simple script:-

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do

    filename=$(basename "$file")     # Get the absolute path of the file
    filename=${filename%.*}          # Getting file-name without the extension part 'tet0002', 'tet0001'
    filename=${filename:3}           # Getting the numerical part '002', '001'

    # To preserve the leading pad '0's, retaining the decimal representation
    # using printf and appending '10#' notation. '-v' for verbose only (can 
    # be removed)

    mv -v "$file" tet"$(printf %04d "$((10#$filename + 1))")".txt

done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name "tet*.txt" -type f -print0)
```

See this in action

```
$ ls tet*
tet0003.txt  tet0005.txt  tet0008.txt

$ ./script.sh
`./tet0005.txt' -> `tet0006.txt'
`./tet0008.txt' -> `tet0009.txt'
`./tet0003.txt' -> `tet0004.txt'
```

Comment: Be careful with this. If you have the files `tet0005.txt` and `tet0006.txt` it looks like `tet0006.txt` will be overwritten with content of the initial `tet0005.txt` before being renamed. See ewcz's comment on the initial post.

Comment: @ThomasWilmotte: Nice catch! Appreciate your comment, I demonstrated an example using those numbers, the author has to take care of the same when running the script.

Comment: I'm not bash expert, but couldn't you just pipe your find statement at the end of your loop with a `sort -r` to get the filenames sorted in the reverse alphabetical order? That way, you can avoid the problem. Maybe `find` have some option for that (need to check the man)